# What is wrong with two xpaths mentioned?

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have two xpaths like this, where I will append the variables which come from the method arguments.

XPath 1:

```
.//tr/td/a[contains(text(),"+projectName+")]/../../td[contains(text(),"+softwareName+")]/../td/div/button[@data-original-title='View Details']
```

XPath 2:

```
.//tr/td/a[contains(text(),"+projectName+")]/../../td/div/button[@data-original-title='Delete Project']
```

I am using those xpaths to click an element. When I run it, I am getting error for XPath2, saying xpath is invalid.

So, I made changes to the XPath2 by putting single quote before the variable projectName, like this.

```
.//tr/td/a[contains(text(),'"+projectName+"')]/../../td/div/button[@data-original-title='Delete Project']
```

When I run this, it executed successfully. I don't know why the first xpath executed without quotes, but the second one failed.

EDIT1:

SAMPLE CODE:

```
clickElement(getXPathofAddButton(softwareName));
```

clickElement is a generic method which has

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath()).click();
```

This is the code for getXPathofAddButton(softwareName), where I give softwareName and that return the xpath. Here, I am not using single quotes, it ran fine.

```
public By getXPathofAddButton(String value)
    {
        try{
            if(value!=null)
            {
                return By.xpath(".//tr/td[contains(text(),"+ value + ")]/../td/div/button[@data-original-title='Add Project']");
            }

        }
        catch(ElementNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }
        return By.xpath("");        
    }
```

Not only this, I have used without single quotes for almost all methods. But, for the below method I got error.

```
clickElement(getXPathofDeleteProjectButton(projectName2));
```

Same like above...

```
public By getXPathofDeleteProjectButton(String projectName)
    {
        try{
            if(projectName!=null)
                return By.xpath(".//tr/td/a[contains(text(),'"+projectName+"')]/../../td/div/button[@data-original-title='Delete Project']");
        }
        catch (ElementNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return By.xpath("");
    }
```

Comment: What are the `projectName` and `softwareName` values you are passing in?

Comment: @alecxe Those are strings in both the cases...

Answer (score 0):

The xpath locator needs string in the xpath you are using to compare text, so when you send string to xpath you surround it in single quote to tell it that this is the text it need to compare

```
a[contains(text(), 'projectName')]
```

In xpath2 you actually did

```
a[contains(text(), projectName)]
```

You didn't give any indication what the string to compare is, only unidentified variable `projectName`.

Comment: but in the xpath1, i didn't give in single quote, but it ran fine... why didn't that gave me error, then?

Comment: @LokeshS I should have. You are probably doing something different there. Can you post the entire relevant code? including the variables definition and the search for the elements (`driver.find(By.xpath())`).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid constructing path expressions using string concatenation in this way - it leaves you wide open to injection attacks if you fail to validate the content of the variables.

I don't know Selenium, but most XPath processors allow you to write an expression that contains a variable reference, for example

```
//tr/td[contains(., $projectName)]/../..
```

and then to bind the variable separately

```
setParameter('projectName', 'myProject')
```

If you can do it this way, it's much more robust and secure.

Comment: What is the exact syntax, how to declare $projectName and how to setParameter, I am using java... I don't know how...

Comment: If you're using the JAXP XPath interface, then you can set a parameter using `XPath.setXPathVariableResolver(new XPathVariableResolver() { ... }`, and in your variable resolver you write a `resolveVariable` method to recognize the parameter's QName and return the relevant value. Yes, it's a bizarre interface (try Saxon's s9api interface instead...)